# Django parameter not in querydict but in view

Tags: django, python-2.7

i'm facing some strange behavior in Django 1.8.3. (Note: I started the project with 1.7.4)
I want to reuse a view in case it gets an get-request, so i defined following urls in the urls.py located at the same place where my settings.py is.

(Note: this is the short version)

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^licenses/$', views.licenses),
    url(r'^licenses/(?P<pool>.*)/$', views.licenses, name='pool'),
)
```

in my views.py i defined following view:

```
def licenses(request, pool=None):
    print request, request.GET
    print pool
```

the template (base.html) calling the view:

```
<li><a href="/licenses/">Licenses</a>
    <ul>
        {% for pool in LICENSE_MENU %}
            <li class="dir"><a href="/licenses/{{ pool }}">{{ pool }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul> 
</li>
```

LICENSE_MENU is a list of licenses passed by a context_processor to the base.html

Everything works almost fine. If i click a license i get redirected to licenses() but the license i clicked doesn't show up in the request.
The output of my shell when i run the testserver and click on the link is following:

```
[06/Oct/2015 12:16:03]"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 129165
<WSGIRequest: GET '/licenses/'> <QueryDict: {}>
[06/Oct/2015 12:16:06]"GET /licenses/ HTTP/1.1" 200 128597
<WSGIRequest: GET '/licenses/ansys/'> <QueryDict: {}>
ansys
[06/Oct/2015 12:16:11]"GET /licenses/ansys/ HTTP/1.1" 200 128851
```

Why does my view print pool although it is not in the request querydict?
What am i missing?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pool isn't part of the get parameters, it is extracted from the url and passed to the view as the variable `pool`. That's why `print pool` works in your view.

If your url was

```
/licenses/?pool=ansys
```

then the url `/licences/` would match the regex `r'^licenses/$'` in your url patterns, and `pool` would be in the get parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the URL parameters that are behind a ? will be extracted and put into the GET. You can get pool from the view function's arguments.